# Tools for deploying solutions

Tags: deployment, solution-package

I'm looking for an easier way of deploying multiple solutions. I know I can write some scripts which handle all my WSP packages (both install and uninstall), but I want something more automated.

Also, I will be distributing some of my solutions, so a nice UI would be good.

I found [SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, but it seems to be outdated and I still need to configure it manually. I also tried [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). It's easier to use and has a great UI, but it's somewhat expensive.

Are there other alternatives? Or do I need to pick one of the above?

Comment: This Q is a bit too open ended. I will allow it since the topic is good, but if we get like 10 answers i will make it Community Wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your ultimate goal? Are you simply trying to avoid CLI?

Personally, I do all of my solution deployment with PowerShell; either create a script or cmdlet to handle multiple scripts, or make something reusable that fits with your internal process. Actual solution deployment is pretty simple, I tend to come from the school of thought that sometimes us IT folk tend to make things harder than they need to be. I'm not sure a "tool" should really be necessary.

Comment: +1 for PowerShell. It is *the* way to deploy and do complex stuff like waiting for packages to be installed etc. I do every deployment 100% with PowerShell (just like my farm configurations)

Comment: I had to +1 your comment-just because I <3 PoSH, haha.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid CLI. I've had complaints that deployment is "messy" and "not user friendly" (not my words). For internal deployment I always use PowerShell, but I am trying to find a cleaner solution for distribution.